# jquery form validation checkbox error display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am currently using [jquery form validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)
for validating a form. A part of the form require the user to select a check box as per below;

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
             <label class="checkbox-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" name="seltype" value="">Price is Firm
             </label>  
             <label class="checkbox-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" name="seltype" value="">Negotiable
             </label> 
              <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
              <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" name="seltype" value="">Swap/Trade
            </label>
        </div>
     </div>
```

My issue is when user submits the form without selecting the chekbox the error display after the first checkbox, i.e. Price is firm. How do I bring the error message to the bottom, i.e. after Swap/Trade option.

**jquery**

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
            $( "#fileupload" ).validate( {

        rules: {seltype:"required"},
        messages: {seltype:"Please select appropriate box"},
                errorElement: "em",
                errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
                    // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
                    error.addClass( "help-block" );

                    if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
                        error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ) );
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter( element );
                    }
                },
                highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
                    $( element ).parents( ".col-xs-5" ).addClass( "has-error" ).removeClass( "has-success" );
                },
                unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $( element ).parents( ".col-xs-5" ).addClass( "has-success" ).removeClass( "has-error" );
                }
            } );

        } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code you specify to insert it after the label:

```
error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ) );
```

So just change that to insert it after the label's parent div:

```
error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ).parent() );
```

Or after the last label:

```
error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ).siblings(':last') );
```